# Simple jQuery code works fine until site is loaded via https://

Tags: jquery, https

I have a simple peice of jQuery code that submits a form and hides/shows some on screen information. It works fine when tested, until loaded via https:// upon which it breaks in IE7. It appears to break totally, with none of the script having any effect. I also get the IE warning that "some elements are insecure".

Does anyone have any experience of this happening? Or even better, a solution! I have to load the page via https as its a credit card payment page.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The three previous answers all mention the problem of a secured "https" page trying to include scripts or other resources (stylesheets, images, etc) from an "http" path...

I would like to add to these, and note that if you have a situation where the same pages could be loaded via *either* http or https, then you can create "protocol-less" URLs---the protocol will be assumed to be the same as the current page. Note this is only needed for accessing resources on different domains (and will only work if those different domains support both http and https), because obviously if you're accessing resources on the same domain, you don't need to start with http:// at all...

For example, each of these three resources would assume either http or https depending on how the current page was accessed:

```
<script src="//www.example.com/whatever.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<img src="//www.example.com/someimage.png" alt="whatever" />
<link href="//www.example.com/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 11):

If you serve a page via `https://` then every resource link should also use `https://`. Look out for

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for all your input. The problem was eventually tracked down to an image mentioned in Thickbox.js.

Because that had a http:// (not https://) url it was causing the error message. The security message that pops up has a yes or no to loading insecure content, and clicking yes was telling the browser to stop loading any jQuery at all.

A tricky one indeed so I thought I would answer myself in the hope it might help someone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the client used HTTPS to request the page, then the page should link to all media (images, scripts, stylesheets) via HTTPS.

If the client used HTTP to request the page, then you should send this HTML fragment within your response:

```
<head>
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="http://my.domain.com/app/media/jquery.js"
    ></script>
</head>
```

If the client used HTTPS to request the page, then you should send this HTML fragment within your response:

```
<head>
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="https://my.domain.com/app/media/jquery.js"
    ></script>
</head>
```

The difference is that, when the client requests the page with HTTPS, the server sends back a link to the jquery script that starts with `https://`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also see a similar behaviour if you are using jquery from
code.jquery.com

eg:

code.jquery.com does not have a valid SSL.

This may cause other scripts to not work correctly.

use the google cdn instead or load the jquery from your own server

Hope it helps

Comment: Not true. As of Oct 1 2013 the code.jquery.com ssl certificate validates without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was using IE 11 as the browser.

Solution: Do not use compatibility mode.   Tools->Compatibility View Settings.

Symptoms:

Program had worked fine in http mode.

Browser reported an error at a line, claiming an identifier was expected.

Browser would not allow debugging on the jquery library file.  File did not
           show up in the list of files to debug, break points could be set on
           the file if accessed via the error message in the developer's
           console log, but the breakpoints were disabled.

Browser clearly showed the file was loaded successfully.

No error appeared when using a different browser.

Hint: I stripped the test program down to loading the jquery library file and a single div that displayed fixed text, so there wasn't any of my own code to go wrong.  That greatly simplified the list of what could be wrong.