# jquery "$(document).ready(function () {" isn't working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, document-ready

Im using the MVC 2 framwork and have added some javascript for expanding divs. It works fine in firefox, chrome, opera and safari but not in internet explorer. I get an 'Object Expected' Error. Here is my code

the jquery import is in the site.master file

```
 <head runat="server">
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The Javascript, in the mvc view: the test alert comes up in IE but test2 doesn't.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("test");

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("test2");
        $(".expandingcontent").hide();

        $(".divexpand").click(function () {
            var divID = "#" + $(this).attr("id").substring(6);
            if ($(divID).is(":hidden")) {
                $(divID).slideDown("slow");
            } else {
                $(divID).hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Ive tried placing the javavscript at the beging of the page, at the end nothing seems to work. Ive also tried using a timeout but no success there either. I'm using IE 8, any help is very much appreciated Thanks!

Comment: On what line the error  occurs? Do you see both alerts?

Comment: maybe the jQuery JavaScript file is not loaded at the time. so you need to ensure that your script is executed after the jquery file is loaded.

Comment: There has to be something else in your HTML. Because this code works just fine in IE...

Comment: Does the test2 appear in other browser?

Comment: Theres nothing other than a few divs, it is running on https though, could that have something to do with it?

Comment: @Jan Zyka  Yeah test 2 appears in the other browsers, its just IE thats causing problems

Comment: i tried your code on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TWNw4/ and its working on IE 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be caused by it not being able to load the jquery.js? Try downloading it and putting it as a local resource.

Comment: Agreed. It works fine on my machine as a local resource. The jquery.js file is probably not fully downloaded by the time IE tries to run the $(document).ready function.

Comment: Yep thats it, d/l Jquery and used as a local resource has fixed my problem. Anyone think the issue importing jquery from the url was caused because my site is using ssl? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056497/simple-jquery-code-works-fine-until-site-is-loaded-via-https

Comment: @Will yes it's very likely - by default browser should alert when `https` website try to load resources from non secure sites. When it's JS files, the browser probably simply won't download it.

Answer (score 3):

Your reference to Google CDN resource is wrong, especially if your site is using SSL.
Change your reference like this and it should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Its because,

> It’s not exactly light reading, but
> [section 4.2 of RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) provides for
> fully qualified URLs that omit
> protocol (the HTTP or HTTPS)
> altogether. When a URL’s protocol is
> omitted, the browser uses the
> underlying document’s protocol
> instead.

Dave Ward explains it more: [Cripple the Google CDN’s caching with a single character](http://encosia.com/2011/01/19/cripple-the-google-cdns-caching-with-a-single-character/)

P.S: Its better to use Google CDN, together with [a local fallback resource in case CDN fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-goo/4825258#4825258) to load

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include the jquery script file before you execute the $(document).ready function.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had an extraneous console.log in the JS and it quietly broke in IE.  It was confusing because when I enabled the IE developer tools it magically started working.  Anyway, check that, too.