# Accessing External jQuery and CSS files

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to access 2 external CSS files and one JS(jQuery) file. I'm adding them to my site like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.externalsite.com/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

and

```
<script src="http://www.externalsite.com/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.externalsite.com/js/default.js"></script>
```

Within default.js, there is a bit of jQuery that control the drop down of my menu. The drop downs don't appear. The HTML code is correct when I view the source.

Am I linking tot he files correctly? Any ideas why I'm not seeing my drop downs?

EDIT:

I'm linking to a HTTP site from a HTTPS site, if that matters.

EDIT 2:

JSFiddle added: http://jsfiddle.net/tvZUG/

Comment: have you tested the code locally without https?

Comment: You are linking the files correctly. Are you sure the external site isn't blocking you from hotlinking their files?

Comment: @Raminson - Yes, still won't work

Comment: @KevinB - No, I own both sites. Nothing is blocked.

Comment: have you loaded jquery before other js files?

Comment: Use Firebug or Chrome Developer tools to see if the css and js are being loaded by the browser. For example, in firebug, you would enable js in the "Script" tab, and then try to select the 'default.js' and jquery. If you see them on the list and can view their content from within firebug, they are correctly linked and the problem is elsewhere (perhaps with your DOM selector).

Comment: @Raminson - Yes, it's loaded before other js

Comment: @Aman - Yes, they are loading, I can see them in the "Scripts" tab of Chrome. What do you mean by a problem with the DOM selector?

Comment: ok, its better to jsfiddle the markup: http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Raminson - Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/tvZUG/

Comment: default.js contains Drop-down Top Navigation js codes?

Comment: @Raminson - I've also pulled it out of default.js and added it directly on the page

Comment: still not working? can you provide the real path to the files that you are loading?

Comment: @Raminson - Sorry, which files are you referring to? What path would you like to see?

Comment: these files http://www.externalsite.com/js/default.js ...

Comment: @Raminson Sorry, I can't provide that info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm linking to a HTTP site from a HTTPS site, if that matters.

Yes it matters. A secure page needs secure resources.

If external site supports https you can get it without defining protocol:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.externalsite.com/js/default.js"></script>
```

And [there's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1056497/1333941). Also take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a type to your script, something like this.

```
<script type="javascript/text" src="http://www.externalsite.com/js/default.js"></script>
```

Are you having any troubles with your css ?

Comment: I'll give it a shot. No, CSS loads fine

Comment: do you have the jquery library set up? if not add `<script type="javascript/text" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">` before all your js files. I would recommend finding your problem with chrome inspector or something.

Comment: hmmm it sounds like you're importing the file correctly, any chance it's the js file that's causing you problems?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have forgot to import jQuery? I can only see the code for the plugin...

Comment: Sorry, jQuery is there, just didn't show it in the sample above. Thanks

Comment: Well I can see the menu. The only problem is that it disappears when you leave the label "Menu 1". Which browser do you use?

Comment: Yep, that's what's confusing me. I'm testing on IE, Chrome and FF

Comment: It's true, its kinda weird. This is the best solution I could make: http://jsfiddle.net/GhpgN/

Answer (score 1):

i think problem can be https that maybe does not allow you to execute javascript files from external sources, you can store files on your server and call them instead.