# javascript drop down stopped working on Wordpress Woocommerce https page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

This is the site I'm currently working on.

http://www.mackeyshotrods.com/store/

When the browser window is resized to 820px a drop down menu appears in the right hand corner of the site. The drop down menu works great on every page except for the check out page. I cant seem to figure it out why the drop down menu isn't working on an HTTPS page. It has to be a JavaScript error of some sort.

To find the page I'm struggling with add a product to the cart and navigate to the checkout page.

http://www.mackeyshotrods.com/store/?product_cat=clothing

Thank you for your help. i hope someone is smart enough to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your jQuery path from:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js

To:

//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js

Good explanation of why your jQuery might be getting blocked here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1056635/2040509