# Javascript - check box doesn't work when page uses SSL (using Kentico CMS)

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, kentico

I have a form page that originally was unencrypted. Now that we have an SSL cert on this web server, I'm trying to set up our page so that the form page will use the SSL cert.

We have a checkbox that indicates that the user has read the privacy policy before he/she submits. There is Javascript code that checks if the box is checked, and if it's not, it flashes a warning and the form doesn't get submitted. When the page is encrypted using SSL, the Javascript code is ignored completely.

Below is the code for the checkbox. As I said, it works fine under http but doesn't react at all when the page uses https.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(event){
        if(!$("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked")){
            alert("内容に同意ください。");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This sounds really spooky. Nevertheless since `attr` reacts differently in the jQuery versions [Link to jQuery Page](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) jakentus answer might be the solution.

Comment: Okay. We're using Kentico so that might have something to do with it. If it were just straight Javascript I wouldn't be so worried.

Comment: Which Kentico Version are you using?

Comment: Version 6. I found out what the problem was - can I answer my own question?

Comment: Yes, you can. you just have to wait some houres. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple jQuery code works fine until site is loaded via https://](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056497/simple-jquery-code-works-fine-until-site-is-loaded-via-https)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. JQuery is running but it was being loaded using http not https (I was unaware jQuery was being used at all).

Once I had jQuery loaded using https, it worked perfectly. Thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: Here is a more [detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1056635/1754037) to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

use $('#checkbox').prop('checked') to check if checkbox is checked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(event){
        if(!$('#input[type='checkbox']').prop('checked')){
            alert("内容に同意ください。");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that and I got the same result. In http, it works correctly (I get the error if the box isn't checked), but in https, the page doesn't care if the box is checked or not.