# Why jQuery script working localhost wamp but not working on web server?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why jQuery Scripts Working On My Localserver When I Creating Script It's Working Fine , But When I Uploaded This Script On Hosting Webserver Then It's Not Working Properly!
Please view this problem and solve please.
my site url: https://offersview.com

Regards,

Sajjad Hossain

Comment: Check the console - you have several errors in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the protocol of your website is https, but the jQuery Scripts is using http protocol. Therefore, jQuery can't be loaded. Change the link like this :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056497/simple-jquery-code-works-fine-until-site-is-loaded-via-https)

Comment: You're welcome. It will be great if you accept my answer so the question will be marked as finished

Answer (score 1):

If using Chrome, go to the menu -> More Tools -> Dev Tools and look at the script errors. You're trying to load jquery at an http URL from an HTTPS location first of all. Even if changed to regular http in the address bar, you're getting other errors like:

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).textition is not a function`